# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor Stop after 10 Pages

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Currently my rule for Sgmllinkextractor is below:

```
     rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("/boards/recentnews.aspx", ),restrict_xpaths=        ('//*[text()[contains(.,"Next")]]'))
        , callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),
        )
```

I want scrapy to stop crawling after it reaches page 10, so I thought it would be something like this:

```
     rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("/boards/recentnews.aspx?page=\d*", ),restrict_xpaths=        ('//*[text()[contains(.,"Next")]]'))
        , callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),
        )
```

But I'm not sure how to do it, the rule applies for 1-10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the callback:

```
def parse_start_url(response):
    page_number = int(re.search('page=(\d+)', response.url).group(1))
    if page_number > 10:
        raise CloseSpider('page number limit exceeded')
    # scrape the data
```

Here's what the line containing regular expression does:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://example.com/boards/recentnews.aspx?page=9"
>>> re.search('page=(\d+)', url).group(1)
'9'
>>> url = "http://example.com/boards/recentnews.aspx?page=10"
>>> re.search('page=(\d+)', url).group(1)
'10'
```

Comment: Thanks, thought there would be a way to include it in the rule.